# MacPorts block some ports from ever being installed (blacklist)

Tags: macports, tex-live

I just had to reinstall MacPorts after my upgrade to Yosemite.  It was a great opportunity to not install tex-live again, because I prefer to use MacTeX.  I believe it got installed as a dependency at one point in time.

What I'm wondering is if there is a way a can prevent it from ever being installed again.  A port blacklist if you will, where even if it's a dependency it will not get installed.  I'm fine with that port with that dependency failing as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a stupid question, but why do you prefer MacTeX? Both the MacPorts TeXLive distribution and MacTeX contain exactly the same software anyway.

Nonetheless, for your specific question, no there is no blacklist. For the special case of LaTeX, you can edit your `macports.conf` and append `/usr/texbin` to the value of `binpath`. For most ports that require LaTeX that should satisfy the dependency, because it is written as `bin:pdflatex:texlive-latex` (e.g. if it needs the `pdflatex` binary) and `bin:`-style dependencies search in `$PATH` (which you've changed by editing the `binpath` setting).

For the cases where this doesn't help, please file bugs and request the Portfile be adjusted to allow MacTeX to satisfy the dependency.

Comment: If that's a stupid question, then my answer is even more ridiculous.  It's really just a matter of preference, nothing more, nothing less.  I just don't like having the redundant installations on my machine because it's hard to track which one is being called where.  I was trying to debug an issue I was having with my R package because it was looking for a specific style file, and it was a pain to track down which version of LaTeX it was using when compiling my package.

Comment: Thanks, I uncommented the bin line and appended the texbin path, hopefully that will work.